# CSGO won't run with an AMD Athlon 5350

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

I am testing a secondary PC of mine with CSGO, and it has a AMD Athlon 5350 processor with R3 graphics and (unfortunately) a Radeon HD 5450. It will run with the crappy graphics card (Radeon HD 5450) but not with the better APU. I do not get an error message, it says I am playing CSGO but no window opens, then it goes back to Online. Because I disabled my HD 5450 in Device Manager, a minute later an error will come up saying your drivers are not properly installed. Should I remove my HD 5450 and see if it works?

An Engine Error eventually came up saying:
[image: The error message]

Comment: I guess this belong on Super User as well, but it has to do with gaming.

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong driver installed because the Key `DriverName` says "Microsoft Basic Render Driver". Try to install the correct graphic drivers.

Comment: @Gerret I have the correct driver. I went to AMD's website to download it again and it said I already have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message, your hardware doesn't support all features needed to run the game. This would be either due to driver issues, or your hardware simply can't support it.

The first thing I would try is to make sure that your HD 5450 drivers are up-to-date and that your monitor is plugged into that video card. If that doesn't work, try removing the HD 5450 and make sure the R3 drivers are up-to-date.

Comment: I completely removed the HD 5450 and CSGO wouldn't launch at all. I now have more of an appreciation for that graphics card. Thanks for the help though!